# How can I fix this joining object issue

Tags: sculpt

I've made the body first as an object, and after making the head as a separate object, joined the objects and joined the vertices with bridge edge loops. In sculpting, it seems like this. I can sculpt the both sides, but one is inverted. For example, the sculpt is + in one, and - in the other.

[image: 1]

Comment: Kindly share the .blend file

Comment: https://www.filemail.com/d/plnwybelknaavay

Answer (score 0):

Click on your mesh, press tab < 3 < A < Alt+N < Recalculate outside.
In addition, check your mesh smoothing by right-clicking on the mesh < smooth, and also check your auto normals.

Comment: You can also just select all and then push Shift+N  to accomplish the same thing, with the normals.

Comment: Thank you so much. How couldn't I think out that.